# License Question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, licensing

Does writing custom code for business process violate the user agreement for use of SharePoint Foundation?  Also, can SharePoint foundation be used for any business practices at all?

I am in a dispute with some co-workers about this.  They seem to think that just because Foundation came with their server package to evaluate, gives them permission to use for their business practices and to be able to write custom code to help drive those business processes.  I say the need to buy it, and they say different.

Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SharePoint foundation for business purpose / development / internet facing site if your server license are covered it. i think your team confused with MSDN license which you cannot use for business purpose but you can use MSDN license for development.

SharePoint Foundation is part of Windows Server,So you need proper licensing of the Windows as well as SQL server.

Always better to contact to MSFT support:

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/contact-us.aspx

i think this will give you more claity.

> If an internet-facing Windows server is licensed to run .NET
>   applications, and use .NET authentication, then it is totally ready to
>   run SharePoint Foundation with SQL Server Express.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b63b3643-d0c7-45d2-8372-364fda348ed0/sharepoint-foundation-licensing-on-internetfacing-server

Comment: This is an intranet behind a firewall does that make a difference since it is not front-facing?

Comment: Nope, that was just an example, Internet facing license is costly then the intranet....But main thing is you can use it if your windows and sql server covered.